# how to add back Ubuntu 22 GUI login session

Tags: login, gui, tty

I run this command on my ubuntu 22 "sudo apt-get purge libelf-dev", then it removed lots of packages. but after that, my network is disconnected, I tried to re-connect the WIFI, but I cannot open the network configure. so I reboot the PC.

After all, I only can see the tty1 terminal login, I tried many repair/recovery, all of them don't fix this. now the problem is that I cannot connect to wifi.  if I cannot connect to wifi, then I can re-install the GUI.

do you know what is missed? how can add GUI login back in the case there is no internet???

thanks.

Comment: Would it be an option to use wired internet, ethernet? Otherwise it is probably best to backup everything that you cannot afford to lose and then make a fresh installation.

Comment: if I have wired internet, how to repair this issue? also how to enable wired internet?

Comment: With wired internet, you could try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libelf-dev`; I don't know how much that was destroyed, but wired internet is much more basic and likely to survive than wifi. Get an ethernet cable and connect to a router (or directly 'to the wall plug' but it is less secure). What computer is it? Can you connect an ethernet cable? Otherwise you can get an adapter via USB, but you might prefer to make a fresh installation.

Comment: @sudodus, there are only ifconfig, iwconfig available in the system. There is no nmcli, network manager. I don’t know it is possible to enable wired network. Such as dhcp .    I have usb Ubuntu, I tried repairing steps. But it does not work

Comment: Which Ubuntu 22 is it? Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS or 22.10; Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS or 22.10; or Ubuntu Core 22? (You asked about GUI, so I could guess Ubuntu Desktop) Ubuntu Desktop has automatic configuration of wired internet, so unless you have removed too much it might work 'out of the box'.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140168/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jackyard).

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu has products that use the *year.month* format (eg. 22.04) that can use the `apt` or `apt-get` commands, but also products using the *year* format (eg. 22) which cannot use the `apt-get` commands as *year* format products (eg. Ubuntu Core 22) are *snap* package only.  Your question mentions 22 (*snap only*) then `apt-get` which won't run on 22; only 22.04 or 22.10.  Please be precise with details & correct your question.